# Why does my ReactJS export statement not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import, export

I'm ultimately trying to dynamically create an object of imported components to export all at once. But in my simple example below, I can't even export an object with 1 component. Why is that?

```js
// index.js
// Card is a standard ReactJS component, exported with export default Card
import Card from './Card';

let Components = {};
Components['Card'] = Card;
// this also doesn't work
// Components['Card'] = require('./Card').default

export default Components;
// Error message: "Attempted import error: 'Card' is not exported from './index.js'"
```

Comment: Can you give the code how you are using the array

Comment: @moshfiqrony It should be an object. My apologies. I just updated the initial `let Components = {}`. Essentially I'm trying to define an object of imported components and then export default it.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you don't have a *named* export `Cards`. You have a *default* export, `Components`, which is an object with a property `Cards`.

If you want to have named export `Cards` then do

```
export {Cards};
```

Or if you don't even need the `Components` object, you can re-export the component directly with

```
export {default as Card} from './Card';
```

However if you really do want to export a default object that holds one or more components as properties, then import it accordingly:

```
import Components from './index.js';
// use Components.Cards were necessary
```

---

See the [`export` documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Two solution here. Firstly when you assign a component into the `Components` object you can assign `Card` as a component like below.

```
Components['Card'] = <Card/>
```

and then use it like this

```
<div>{Components.Card}</div>
```

Secondly and My favorite is, whatever you have done in the `index.js` file to store the component is ok. But when you are using it use it like below.

```
<Component.Card/>
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-davinci-nyj5h?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you for your response, and my apologies, I don't think my question was clear. I simplified my code to this: `export const Card = require('./Card').default;`. This works and it allows me to import and export the component at the same time. I'm wondering how I can export the component dynamically if I have a variable like `let a = Card`, It doesn't work if I do `export const a = require(`./${a}`).default` because `export const a` gives an error of a is already defined.

Comment: I am still not sure then what you are trying to achieve.